# Computer failing to start after updating from Ubuntu 15.04 to 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.04

I have a computer dedicated to Ubuntu and I wanted to update the operating system to a LTS version after I was having problems with programs (like Chrome) no longer working since the version of Ubuntu I was using no longer being supported.

I ran the "software updater" to preform the update and everything went well (as far as I could tell) until the computer wanted to restart, it was just showing a blank screen. I (perhaps stupidly) switched off and on the computer with the power button on the computer itself. When it came back on I got the following message:

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 2013302/58957824 files, 114215880/235816448 blocks
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: AppArmor initialization.
See 'Systemct1 status apparmor.service' for details.
    Mounting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
[ OK ] Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
     Starting Show Plymouth Boot screen...
[ OK ] Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
    Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
[ OK ] Mounted Arbitrary Executable File Formats System.
[ OK ] Listening on Load/Save RF Kill switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
[ OK ] Started clean up any mess keft by 0dns-up.
    Starting Nameserver information manager...
[ OK ] Started Enable support for additional executable binary formats.
```

Once this appears, the computer doesn't go any further.

What can I do to get my computer going again?

[Link to photo of screen with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLF5i.jpg)

Comment: There could be any number of things that went wrong here. I would suggest you burn a copy of a live cd, boot up with the live cd. You will be able to access your files on the installation and perform crucial backups and repair. Thereafter proceed to fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)